# SQL Decimal to Java Decimal

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, decimal

I am writing a JDBC application. My Task is to get the data from SQL server encrypt them and then store them in another table as `varbinary` field. I have successfully converted all sql data types to binary except decimal field.

I am using `getBytes()` method of JDBC to get the bytes for this decimal field. But the bytes I am receiving are not valid bytes for example I am running one query in sql which will convert decimal to binary as

```
declare @deci decimal(18,2)
set @deci = 2.33
print cast(@deci as varbinary)
```

as a result I get -- `0x12020001E9000000` (for my application to work properly I need this binary on JDBC side) : (5 bytes)

but on the JDBC side I get bytes as (for the same value) -- `2,1,-23,3,0` (5 bytes)(I am printing the value of each byte)

can anybody help me to understand the difference?? and how to convert these JDBC bytes to above `varbinary`

Thanks in advance